# Domain/Points of differentiability

Tags: real-analysis, functions, derivatives

How would I find the domain or points of a function where it is differentiable? Let's say I had the function $f: \mathbb R \rightarrow \mathbb R$ defined by $f(x) = |x|$. I know that a function $f: \mathbb R \rightarrow \mathbb R$ differentiable at $x_0 \in \mathbb R$ means that for all $\epsilon > 0$, there exists a $\delta > 0$ such that for some $L \in \mathbb R$, $|\frac{f(x) - f(x_0)}{x - x_0} - L| < \epsilon$ for all $x \in \mathbb R$ with $|x - x_0| < \delta$. However, I'm not sure how to find all possible values of $x_0$ from this alone, so am I supposed to be doing this a different way? I'm confused.

All responses are much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For $x>0$ the function is just $f(x)=x$ and you know that this is differentiable.

For $x<0$ the function is just $f(x)=-x$ and this is differentiable.

So the only question is differentiability at $x=0$. Here consider $\lim_{h \to 0} \frac {f(0+h)-f(0)} h=\lim_{h \to 0} \frac {|h|} h$. Since the limit here through positive values of $h$ is $1$ and the limit through negative values of $h$ is $-1$, the limit does not exist, so $f$ is not differentiable at $0$.

Comment: Thanks for the response.

Answer (score 0):

*This is a very broad topic!*

Let's give some elements however.

**Base differentiable real functions**

As differentiable functions have nice properties, we first try to define differentiable functions. For example, one can prove that constant, polynomials, $e^x$, $\log x$, entire functions are differentiable.

**Building differentiable functions from differentiable functions**

After that, you can prove that, sum, product, ratio, composition of differentiable functions are differentiable. $\int f$ is differentiable if $f$ is continuous...

Using the facts above allows you to quickly prove that a lot of functions are differentiable! Like $x \mapsto \log \left( \frac{x^{24} + 347 x^2 +1}{x^2 + e^x} \right) + \sin \left(\int_0^x \vert t \vert \ dt\right)$...

**The example of $\vert f \vert$**

Coming back to your precise example, if $f$ is differentiable, one can prove that $\vert f \vert$ is also differentiable at $a$ if $f(a) \neq 0$. $f$ will be differentiable at $a$ if $f(a)=0$ if and only if $f^\prime(a) = 0$. Nice exercise!

**The "interesting" cases!**

After all those "standard cases", there are some cases where you need to come back to the basic definition and look at what happens in details.

Like a continuous function that is nowhere differentibale. Look [here](http://www.mathcounterexamples.net/function-everywhere-continuous-nowhere-differentiable/) for details.